# Highcharts chart date issue

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

It's the first time I use *Highcharts* and there is something missing, I'm sure.
I'm trying to translate its calendar months but it seems it doesn't work although everywhere I read this should be the best way.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
    months: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 
            'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre']
        }
    }); 
    var reviewAvgContainer = $('#reviewAvgcontainer');

        reviewAvgContainer.highcharts({
            credits : {
              enabled: false
            },
            data: {
                table: 'reviewAvgData'
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: reviewAvgContainer.data('title')
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    month: '%B'
                }
            },

            yAxis: {
                min : 0,
                max: 10,
                allowDecimals: false,
                title: {
                    text: graphTrans.generalGraph['RATINGS']
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem comes when I add  `xAxis: {`, particularly `type: 'datetime'`. It seems it doesn't like it and the date appears completely disrupted as following:

1. Jan   00:00:00.001   00:00:00.002   00:00:00.003  00:00:00.004   00:00:00.005   00:00:00.006

Instead of  Février to Août.

When I remove type: `'datetime'` everything works but the months are not translated anymore

I have not a clue about what it is. Any idea?

Comment: Roberto, what do your dates in your "reviewAvgData" table look like? What format are they in?

Comment: I found the answer. I'm an idiot but I'll leave this here for those who run into the same issue.
The issue is caused buat a bad formatted date, so if these dates disruption arose, you ought to have a look at the date format you're passing in to the chart

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution!